# RegEx - Take all numeric characters following a text character

Tags: .net, regex

Given a string in the format: XXX999999v99 (where X is any alpha character and v is any numeric character and v is a literal v character) how  can I get a regex to match the numeric characters following the v? So far I've got 'v\d\d' which includes the v but ideally I'd like just the numeric part.

As an aside does anyone know of a tool in which you can specify a string to match and have the regex generated? Modifying an existing regex is one thing but I find starting from scratch painful!

*Edit: Re-reading this question I realise it reads like a homework assignment! However I can assure you it's not, the strings I'm trying to match represent product versions appended to product codes. The current code uses all sorts of substring expressions to retrieve the version part.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
v(\d+)$
```

- `v` : matches the literal v
- `\d`: a single digit
- `\d+`: one or more digits.
- `()`: grouping that also remembers
  the matched part, which can be used
  later
- `$`: end of line anchor

Comment: When I try this the match includes the v character. Is it possible to remove this and just return the numeric part? Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Simon : When the regex finds a match, the first group always contains the full string that matched the regex. You should check the second group if you need to get only the captured part.

Comment: Duh, just realised - remove the v char from the regex!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a capture group:

```
Regex.Match("XXX999999v99",@"v(\d+)").Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Be careful, if there is no match in the original string, this code will throw an exception when trying to access Groups[1].